Las propiedades que son Css en general no me funcionan en VSC
En realidad estoy empezando a programar en archivos .CSS y eh estado siguiendo un tutorial de Youtube para hacer una pagina web que contenga un login y registro junto, entonce en la parte de los estilos no lo eh podido hacer debido a que no me deja poner ningun tipo de propiedades del CSS, y descargue el plugins de Css y pues la verdad, me ha pasado varias veces que me sale como si no existiera esa propiedad y despues de un rato es que me sale nuevamente, si alguien sabe como solucionarlo, por diganme.

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Asegurate que tu archivo .css se encuentre en la misma carpeta de tu proyecto.
Recuerda que en tu index debes agregar una etiqueta link dentro del head con el siguiente formato: <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">, por ejemplo
El nombre que estoy usando de ejemplo de estilos.css, debe llevar el nombre que tiene tu archivo css.
En caso de que tengas niveles de carpetas (directorios), debes especificarlos en la etiqueta link en si atributo href. Es decir, si tu archivo está dentro de una carpeta llamada "Estilos/estilos.css", así tal cual debe ir en la propiedad.
